# Angular form returning ERROR TypeError: "_co.service.formData is undefined"?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I'm trying to make an form in angular 7 and get inout in that but the form is giving the following error  : ERROR TypeError: "_co.service.formData is undefined"

now here is my code for the html part of the component :-

```
<form (sumbit)="signUp(form)" autocomplete="off" #form="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
     <input name="Name" class="form-control" #Name="ngModel"  [(ngModel)]="service.formData.Name"  required>
  </div>
</form>
```

while this is the type script code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../../shared/user.service';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-agent-signup',
  templateUrl: './agent-signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agent-signup.component.css']
})
export class AgentSignupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  signUp(form:NgForm)
  {

  }
}
```

and this is the code for user.service :-

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {UserData} from './user.model';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
 const API_URL=environment.apiUrl;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  formData : UserData;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  createUser(formData:UserData)
  {
     return this.http.post(API_URL+'/user/signup',formData);
  }
}
```

and this is the the user.model class :-

```
export class UserData{

  public Email:string;
  public Password:string;
  public  Rera_no:string;
  public Name:string;
  public Company_name:string;
}
```

and i'm getting the following error :-
ERROR TypeError: "_co.service.formData is undefined"
can anybody tell me where i'm going wrong and how can i correct it ?

Comment: where have you defined `service.formData.Name` ?

Comment: @programoholic please see the updated code

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @JohanRin https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwhgmb

Answer (score 2):

you are initializing with the Class object but not creating it's object though. So 
do changes like this in your component

**from**

> formData : UserData;

**to**

> formData = new UserData();

in your template

```
<form (sumbit)="signUp(form)" autocomplete="off" #form="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
     <input name="Name" class="form-control" #Name="ngModel"  [(ngModel)]="service.formData?.Name"  required>
  </div>
</form>
```

I hope this wil solve your issue

**EDIT**

you are using Object variable as `ngModel` which is not created in the Service yet. so try to initialize it first with empty string.

```
export class UserData{

  public Email:string;
  public Password:string;
  public  Rera_no:string;
  public Name: string = '';
  public Company_name:string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you need to call method from service `UserService`  in component with form `AgentSignupComponent` . So you need to call createUser method in `AgentSignupComponent`;

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../../shared/user.service';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-agent-signup',
  templateUrl: './agent-signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agent-signup.component.css']
})
export class AgentSignupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:UserService) { } //You use DI this but dont call method;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  signUp(form:NgForm) {
    this.service.createUser(form); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a `console.log(service);` in your `InOnInit()` function of your `AgentSignupComponent` class. Observe what properties you can see in your console. This error means it cannot access the UserData object in your formData variable. So you need to initiate a UserData object and assign a value to the variable. Change  `formData : UserData;` to  `formData = new UserData();`